# PHP , Ler arquivos txt onde cada registro tem várias linhas

Tags: php, txt

Sei que pareço percistente nesse tipo de pergunta, mas a todo momento as duvidas so aumentam..kk
peciso importar um txt onde cadas registro que sera incluido no BD tem pelo menos 3 linhas

exemplo:

> B121023160CAMPO1COM SUBSTRING
> 6121023160CAMPO2COM SUBSTRING
> 7121023160CAMPO3COM SUBSTRING
> 8121023160CAMPO4COM SUBSTRING
> B121023160CAMPO1COM SUBSTRING
> 6121023160CAMPO2 COM SUBSTRING
> 7121023160CAMPO3 COM SUBSTRING
> 8121023160CAMPO4 COM SUBSTRING
> B121023160CAMPO1 COM SUBSTRING
> 6121023160CAMPO2 COM SUBSTRING
> 7121023160CAMPO3 COM SUBSTRING
> 8121023160CAMPO 4 COM SUBSTRING

viu o padrao? a denominação de registro começa com a letra B no começo da string
em seguida vem uma sequencia de linha com 6,7 e 8 que sao campos complementares.
a duvida é como faço para ler esse arquivo de 3 em 3 linhas ou uma maneira que a cada letra inicial B reconheça como um novo registro?

o que eu ja fiz foi copiar um codigo da net isso mas sinceramente nao entendi como faria pra capturar e unir todos campos numa string tipo
$registro=" $campo1.$campo2.$campo3.$campo4";

mysql_insert($registro);

este codigo foi o que copiei

```
fgf$arq = "02320220960002.CAR";
    $handle = fopen($path.$arq,"r");
    $grupos = array();
    while( !feof($handle) ){
$line = trim(fgets($handle));
$codigo = substr($line,0,1);
if($codigo == 'B'){
    $grupos[] = array(
        'local' => substr($line,4,3),
        'rota' => substr($line,8,13),
        'matricula' =>  substr($line,21,8)
        
    );
    continue;
}

if($codigo == '8'){
    if(empty($grupos)){
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('314 alcançado sem nenhum 312');
    }
    $idx = count($grupos)-1;
    
    $grupos[$idx][] = $nota;
    }
    }fclose($handle);
    print_r($grupos);
```

como eu faria para mostrar essa string ao inves de usar o print_r(); ? fazendo om laço FOR? FOREACH? nao sei como,

se alguem tivar outra sugestão , ou explicar esse codigo pra mim,nao entendi como isso vai unir as 3 linhas pois aki nao deu certo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse código vai fazer mesclar as linhas como você quer, após isso já é com você.

```php
$registers = [];
$index = -1;
foreach (file('LOCAL_DO_SEU_ARQUIVO', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) as $line) {
    if (substr($line, 0, 1) === 'B') {
        $index++;
        $registers[$index] = $line;
    } else {
        $registers[$index] .= $line;
    }
}
```

Se você executar `echo print_r($registers);` você terá a seguinte saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => B121023160CAMPO1COM SUBSTRING6121023160CAMPO2COM SUBSTRING7121023160CAMPO3COM SUBSTRING8121023160CAMPO4COM SUBSTRING
    [1] => B121023160CAMPO1COM SUBSTRING6121023160CAMPO2 COM SUBSTRING7121023160CAMPO3 COM SUBSTRING8121023160CAMPO4 COM SUBSTRING
    [2] => B121023160CAMPO1 COM SUBSTRING6121023160CAMPO2 COM SUBSTRING7121023160CAMPO3 COM SUBSTRING8121023160CAMPO 4 COM SUBSTRING
)
```

O código é bem simples, acho que dispensa explicações, a não ser pelas funções `substr()` e `file()`, mas você acha sobre elas no site do PHP.

Comment: obrigado, me ajudou muito.

Answer (score 0):

Bom depois de ter arrumado o codigo segue como ele ficou pra mim. ficou bom, pois fiz um loop pra ler todos arquivos do diretorio e depois um loop pra importar os campos

```
 for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++)
{
 $m = str_pad($i,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
    for ($c=42; $c<=61; $c++)
    {
    $arquivo = $local.$referencia.$m.$c."002.CAR";
    if (file_exists($path.$arquivo)) 
        {
    $doc[] = $path.$arquivo;
    $importa = true;
        }
    }
}

if ($importa = true )
 {
 foreach ($doc as $d)
{
 
foreach (file($d, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) as $line) 
{

if (substr($line, 0, 1) === 'B') 
    {
    $index++;
    $registers[$index] .= "('".substr($line,4,3);           
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,20,8);     
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,8,13);     
    } 
if (substr($line, 0, 1) === '6') 
    {
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,28,30);            
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,58,5);         
        $comp               = substr($line,63,30);      
    $registers[$index] .= "','".str_replace("'"," ",$comp);
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,93,5);          
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,99,5);          
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,116,8);            
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,124,15);           
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,149,5);             
    }
if (substr($line, 0, 1) === '7') 
    {
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,28,3);             
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,31,3);             
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,34,3);             
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,37,3);             
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,40,3);             
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,43,3);             
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,46,3);             
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,49,3);             
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,52,3);             
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,55,3);             
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,58,3);             
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,61,12);                
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,85,1);             
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,86,1);             
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,92,5);             
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,97,5);             
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,102,5);                
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,107,5);                
    }

if (substr($line, 0, 1) === '8') 
    {
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,29,6);                 
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,35,6);             
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,41,2);                 
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,43,2);                 
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,45,2);                 
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,55,8);                     
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,77,8);                 
            $nome           = substr($line,85,40);                  
    $registers[$index] .= "','". str_replace("'"," ",$nome);
            $nome_da_mae    = substr($line,149,40);                 
    $registers[$index] .= "','".str_replace("'"," ",$nome_da_mae);
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,189,40);                   
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,239,11);                   
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,267,12);                   
    $registers[$index] .= "','".substr($line,279,8)."');";              
    }
}
for ($c=1; $c<=$index; $c++)
    {
$qryinsert = "REPLACE INTO cadastro_novo ('campos aki') VALUES".$registers[$c];
     
     mysql_query($qryinsert)or die(mysql_error());
     }
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).